# Mysql duplicate entry error magento

Tags: mysql, magento

I have uploaded a sql database file of demo store of magento. The instruction said to change the ***web/secure/base_url*** and ***web/unsecure/base_url*** but I cant find it in the core_config_data table. It is not there.

However when I try to add it myself it wont add and gives me a duplicate entry error. Can anyone please tell me what is the reason?

UPDATE `perftcom_magento`.`core_config_data` SET  `path` =  'web/secure/base_url' WHERE  `core_config_data`.`config_id` =3882

MySQL error:

> 1062 - Duplicate entry 'default-0-web/secure/base_url' for key
>   UNQ_CORE_CONFIG_DATA_SCOPE_SCOPE_ID_PATH

Comment: Try this **SELECT * FROM perftcom_magento.core_config_data WHERE   path = 'web/secure/base_url'** to find the duplication

Comment: Is this Magento 1 or Magento 2? Can you check in your original database file that the core_config_data table exists?